# Discord.js buttons package

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need little help. I want to set my buttons to be functional. I'm using this package [discord-buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons)
So, i created two buttons: for cleaning channel and locking channel.
I don't know how to set them to work. 
There is code.

```
let opcijaKanala = new MessageButton()
.setStyle("green")
.setLabel("Otkljucaj kanal")
.setID("unlockChannel")
```

Maybe I need something like this?

```
client.on('buttonClicked' //... )
```

Comment: You should update to v13 and use the built in MessageComponent builders, discord-buttons and v12 are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The event for button clicks is `interactionCreate`

Something a little like this may work

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (ctx) => {
  if(!ctx.isButton()) return // filter out commands and non-buttons
  if(ctx.customId === "foobar") {
    // do something amazing
  }
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: @RileyHookins Huh strange. Worked for me... Check out https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html (discordjs.guide's page on buttons)

Comment: I believe you. Not for me hah. Nevermind, I don't have much time to mess with this, but thank you for your answer :) +

Comment: azet.dev#0191 if you can add me, we can see my code, I don't know why this doesn't work.